# JQuery confirmation dialog after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to validate, on server side, if a person with a given registration number is already on the database. If this person is already registered, then I proceed with the program flow normally. But, if the number is not already registered, then I'd like to show a confirmation dialog asking if the operator wants to register a new person with the number entered and, if the operator answers yes, then the person will be registered with the number informed on the form on it's submission.

I've tried

Server side(PHP):

```
if (!$exists_person) {
  $resp['success'] = false;
  $resp['msg'] = 'Do you want to register a new person?';
  echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

Client side:

```
function submit(){
  var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
      ,dataType: 'json'
      ,url: 'myPHP.php'
      ,async: 'true'
      ,data: data
      ,error: function(response){
        alert('response');
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

I can't even see the alert, that's where I wanted to put my confirmation dialog, with the message written on server side. Other problem, how do I resubmit the entire form appended with the operator's answer, so the server can check if the answer was yes to register this new person?

**EDIT**

I was able to solve the problem this way:

Server side(PHP):

```
$person = find($_POST['regNo']);
if ($_POST['register_new'] === 'false' && !$person) {
    $resp['exists'] = false;
    $resp['msg'] = 'Do you want to register a new person?';
    die(json_encode($resp)); //send response to AJAX request on the client side
} else if ($_POST['register_new'] === 'true' && !$person) {
    //register new person
    $person = find($_POST['regNo']);
}

if($person){
    //proceed normal program flow
}
```

Client side:

```
function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
    var ajax1 = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST'
        , dataType: 'json'
        , async: 'true'
        , url: 'myPHP.php'
        , data: data
        , success: function (response) {
            if (!response.exists && confirm(response.msg)) {
                document.getElementById('register_new').value = 'true'; //hidden input
                dados = $('#myForm').serialize(); //reserialize with new data
                var ajax2 = $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST'
                    , dataType: 'json'
                    , async: 'true'
                    , url: 'myPHP.php'
                    , data: data
                    , success: function () {
                        document.getElementById('register_new').value = 'false';
                        $('#myForm').unbind('submit').submit();
                    }
                });
            } else if (response.success) {
                alert(response.msg);
                $('#myForm').unbind('submit').submit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a `confirm()` ?

Comment: The alert will only show on error. Perhaps your ajax request is succeeding.

Comment: add  `success : function(response) { alert (response);}` before `error` callback.  It should show the `alert`. When the `alert` is shown then you can replace `alert` with `confirm`.

Comment: @Naruto yes, but it wasn't simply a confirm, there were more business logic involved.

Comment: @Moob, yes, I'm a newbie with AJAX and that was my first try, I thought as if it was like ExtJS that, if you returned an AJAX containing success: false it executes the error callback, and that was what I was doing. But, with JQuery, the success callback will be executed whenever the request succeeds.

Comment: @Venky, you are right, see the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your PHP.

The problem is (1) You are doing the alert inside of an error callback, and your request isn't failing, so you don't see the alert. (2) You are alerting the string `'response'` instead of the variable `response`.

It is also worth noting that you should be using the `.done()` and `.fail()` promise methods (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Here is the fixed JS:

```
function submit() {

  var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

  // Same as before, with the error callback removed
  var myAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'myPHP.php',
    async: 'true',
    data: data
  });

  // The request was successful (200)
  myAjaxRequest.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // The data variable will contain your JSON from the server
    console.log(data);
    // Use a confirmation dialog to ask the user your question
    // sent from the server
    if (confirm(data.msg)) {
      // Perform another AJAX request
    }
  });

  // The request failed (40X)
  myAjaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });

  return false;
}
```

Also, you are setting a 'status' in PHP and checking that in the JS (I presume). What you want to be doing is setting a HTTP status code from the server, as below:

```
if (!$exists_person) 
{
    $resp['msg'] = 'Do you want to register a new person?';

    // 400 - Bad Request
    http_response_code(400);

    echo json_enconde($resp);
}
```

Then, jQuery will determine whether the request failed based on the status code you respond with. `200` is a successful request, and `400` numbers are fail.

Check out this page for a full list: https://httpstatuses.com/

Comment: This doesn't answer the second part of his question *"Other problem, how do I resubmit the entire form appended with the operator's answer, so the server can check if the answer was yes to register this new person?"*

Comment: @Alex'TheZanke'Howard You're right I need to append the answer given by the operator with the old data, so, when I resubmit the form to myPHP.php I'll check the answer to know what to do. Is there a way to append the answer to the previously submitted data?

Comment: @LeandroJacques It sounds like you are using this function as an onsubmit event handler. You should assign `e` (for _event_) in the function arguments, and then call `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the function. You can look at my answer below for an example of how to do this, and also for an answer to the second part of your question.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for your answer, it doesn't work as you posted. If I use the success callback it works, but, as soon as the server returns the response, the page is reloaded and the dialog is not displayed and I lose the response. If I use the way you posted myAjaxRequest.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR), this function is not called and the dialog is not shown in any way. With the success callback, while debugging line by line, the dialog is shown, but as soon as I click play to continue the script the page reloads, I don't know why, and all fields are cleaned. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this is a two part question; I'll try my best to answer both parts:

**Part 1**: How to detect if success is false and trigger the confirmation popup?

In jQuery.ajax the error handler is triggered based on response code. This is probably not what you want. You can use your success handler and test the value `res.success` to see if it's true or false. It would be something along the lines of:

```
function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'myPHP.php',
    async: 'true',
    data: data
  }).done(function(res) {
    if (!res.success) {
      alert(res.msg);
    }
  });
}
```

**Part 2**: How do I resubmit with a confirmation?

Working off of our previous code we will make some changes that allow for `submit()` to be passed an argument `registerNew`. If `registerNew` is true we will pass it as a param to the ajax handler in the PHP so it knows we want to register a new person. The Javascript will look something like this:

```
function submit(e, registerNew) {
  if (e) e.preventDefault();

  var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
  var ajax_options = {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'myPHP.php',
    async: 'true',
    data: data
  };

  ajax_options.data.register_new = !!registerNew;

  $.ajax(ajax_options).done(function(res) {
    if (!res.success && confirm(res.msg)) {
      submit(null, true);
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see here, we are passing a new `register_new` param in the data in our ajax options. Now we need to detect this on the PHP side, which is easy enough and looks like this (this goes in your php ajax handler):

```
if ($_POST["register_new"]) {
  // new user registration code goes here
} else {
  // your existing ajax handler code
}
```

Comment: I was making it not on the onsubmit of the form, but on the onclick of the submit button. Now I tried to change to the onsubmit, but the funcion is never called and I can't do e.preventDefault(). My HTML <form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" target="_parent" onsubmit="submit()">

Comment: It could still work on the submit button's click event.

Comment: If you want to use it as an event handler I'd suggest using javascript to add it as a listener in your javascript file. You'll want to say `document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', submit);` and then remove the `onsubmit="submit()"` from your markup. This will also help you separate markup and logic a little more.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANKS! Now I'll try your solution for the resubmission of the form, if everything works, I'll give it as the final answer and upvote it.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem partially, but helped me to solve it the way I needed, so upvoted. The answer to my question is on my edit. The only issue I'm having is that the page is not being reloaded after submission.

Comment: Issue solved, my json was misspelled coming from the server, I wrote sucess instead of success and on the client side I was waiting for response.success ;)

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Add confirm inside submit function

```
function submit(){
  var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
if (confirm('Are you ready?')) {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
      ,dataType: 'json'
      ,url: 'myPHP.php'
      ,async: 'true'
      ,data: data
      ,error: function(response){
        alert('response');
      }
  });
 }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It's not what I was asking for. This way you will only confirm at the client side before sending the request to the server. I need to validate on the server side before showing the dialog confirming if a new person will be registered.